# I tried to run React Native app for the first time and an Error across me. undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors')

Tags: react-native

I have just created new React Native App and when I try to run it on iOS it's ruining without any problem but when I run it on android it is showing me an Error says

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arguments[i])') (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:3573)

This error shown in the (Red screen) `React Native Error Screen` after the app has been installed on the device.

Comment: This might be help - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable solution but worked for me

I guessed that the problem was some kind of dependency upgrade, and because React Native does not come locked to working versions, something got published and broke it.

I grabbed a yarn.lock from a project from over the weekend, pasted that into my project's yarn.lock file and then did yarn at the command line to have it automatically prune/lock things back up. Somewhere in that mess, it grabbed the right stuff and now I can use Android again. Not a great fix, but hopefully it helps!

1. Copy this [yarn.lock](https://gist.github.com/GantMan/347fb4206fa7be141ff7133ba4859afd) contents
2. Past it over your project's `yarn.lock` contents
3. run yarn in the CLI

**Note:** I got this solution from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23092#issuecomment-456282558).

Answer (score 0):

> its worked for me install this dependency
>
> npm i object.getownpropertydescriptors

[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.getownpropertydescriptors)

Answer (score -1):

temporary Fix:

Add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@babel/helpers": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.2.0"
  }
```

Then run `rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn start --reset-cache`